# Can I load all shipping methods automatically on the shopping cart page without selecting a country first?

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, shipping-methods

Can I load all my shipping methods automatically on the shopping cart page without prior to selecting a country?

By Magento default, you have to select your country where you want to ship your order to. Then you have to hit the button **'Get a quote'** for the '**Estimate Shipping and Tax**'. But I want to skip this step by showing all my shipping methods automatically as soon as you are on this page.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you just need to force the called to estimate shipping. There are a variety of free auto-quote extns that will do this for you and are used on many sites.